# How do I replace the Magento favicon?

Tags: favicon, magento

I'm trying to replace the Magento favicon, but I can't seem to find it. Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add the favicon meta tag to your theme's header and point it to the favicon in your root. A more complex way (I think) is replacing the favicon in `/skin/frontend/theme/interface/favicon.ico`, but I never had any success with that method.

Comment: The path is basically `$MAGENTO/skin/frontend/package/theme/favicon.ico` thanks it fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

- First point, check the source of your front page

  - if you found a meta like this: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="a/path/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />` just change the favicon in the named path
- Else, browsers try to get the favicon to the root of your website so:

  - either you put a file `favicon.ico` at this place
  - or you put a meta like above with the good path to your favicon.

Comment: This only works if you have just one shop. Better upload the favicon to the theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using rewrite and completely bypass Magento:

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico$ /images/favicon.ico [L]
```

Comment: It works, but it's not preferred I think. Better do it right in the template, less confusing. And if you have multiple shops with multiple designs and multiple favicons, you need to use conditions in the htaccess. All in all you better upload the favicon to the template.